# Сcылка на скачиваение и просмотр PDF

Tags: php, joomla

Есть некая ссылка к api которую не должны видит посетители. Данная ссылка возвращает готовый pdf

Надо сделать 2 вещи

1) по данной ссылки /index.php?option=com_laboratorija&task=downloadPDF&id=0501915 скачать PDF
Пишу такой код

```
self::auth(); //Авторизация на api сервере
$url = self::apiRequest("/repengine/ord_report_pdf/" . $id . '/'); //получение PDF c API сервера
    $file=$url;
    header("Location: $file");
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$id.'.pdf"');
    readfile($file);
    exit();
```

Файл отправляется на скачивает но пустой как победить?

2) Просмотр PDF /index.php?option=com_laboratorija&task=viewPDF&id=0501915
Пишу так

```
self::auth(); //Авторизация на api сервере
$url = self::apiRequest("/repengine/ord_report_pdf/" . $id . '/'); //получение PDF c API сервера
    $file=$url;
    header("Location: $file");
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    readfile($file);
    exit();
```

Так же как и в первом случаи браузер выдает PDF но пустой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Скачать PDF

```
            self::auth();  //Авторизация на api сервере
            $url = self::apiRequest("/repengine/ord_report_pdf/" . $id . '/'); //получение PDF c API сервера
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$id.'.pdf"');
            echo $url; //ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО.
```

2) Посмотреть PDF

```
                self::auth();  //Авторизация на api сервере
                $url = self::apiRequest("/repengine/ord_report_pdf/" . $id . '/'); //получение PDF c API сервера
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            echo $url;
```